# Juju deploy charm juju-gui fails with connection time out

Tags: networking, juju

I am using Juju 1.18.4.
The environment is bootstrapped and here is the 
**juju status**

`environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.4
    dns-name: poLap8.pvt.domain.net
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-9e78ad8c-5465-11e4-90b6-c80aa9bbfa5a/
    series: trusty
services: {}`

I am tring to install juju-gui on machine:0 (aka poLap8.pvt.domain.net) using this command
**juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui --debug**
`2014-10-16 12:18:47 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:302 running juju-1.18.4-trusty                                               -amd64 [gc]
2014-10-16 12:18:47 DEBUG juju api.go:171 trying cached API connection settings
2014-10-16 12:18:47 INFO juju api.go:242 connecting to API addresses: [poLap8.pv                                               t.kaseya.net:17070]
2014-10-16 12:18:47 INFO juju apiclient.go:114 state/api: dialing "wss://poLap8.                                               pvt.kaseya.net:17070/"
2014-10-16 12:18:47 INFO juju apiclient.go:124 state/api: connection established
2014-10-16 12:20:55 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 cannot download charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-10": Cannot access the charm store. Are you connected to the internet? Error details: Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-10: dial tcp 91.189.95.66:443: connection timed out`

The Server[MasterShifu] were I am running juju command has dual NIC's - one Ethernet and one wlan. 
Ethernet interface is connected to private network[192.168.0.0] and run the DHCP, DNS and Proxy server for the network. 
Wlan interface is connect to a external routable network and has access to internet.
I am able to access the juju store from this machine, here is the output

`curl store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-10
{"cs:trusty/juju-gui-10":{"canonical-url":"cs:trusty/juju-gui-10","revision":10,"sha256":"5b78eeea39c5425d8e9f95db85054fe34df932424a393af6c98a8577ef05f94f","digest":"francesco.banconi@canonical.com-20141003150150-yzikfrwp4wcbpn27"}}`

**Machine:0 aka poLap8.pvt.domain.net**
Has just Ethernet interface enable and in the 192.168.0.108 network - Has http_proxy and https_proxy configured to [MasterShifu] server. I am able to access the juju store url from this machine also and here is the output

`export | grep http
declare -x http_proxy="192.168.0.1:3128"
declare -x https_proxy="192.168.0.1:3128"`

`curl https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-10
{"cs:trusty/juju-gui-10":{"canonical-url":"cs:trusty/juju-gui-10","revision":10,"sha256":"5b78eeea39c5425d8e9f95db85054fe34df932424a393af6c98a8577ef05f94f","digest":"francesco.banconi@canonical.com-20141003150150-yzikfrwp4wcbpn27"}}ubuntu@poLap8:~$`

I am still clueless on the cause of the issue. 
Provide me some hints on where to check further to fix this issue.

Comment: Try setting http_proxy in the shell environment in which you run juju deploy. The log message for dialing the store does not look like it is trying a proxy. Trying a proxy log message looks like: 2014-10-16 14:05:09 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Aprecise%2Fghost: http: error connecting to proxy http://192.168.254.254:8080: dial tcp 192.168.254.254:8080: connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. tried `.bashrc`, `/etc/environment`, `.juju/environments.yaml`, `.juju/environments/maas.jenv` none worked.

`juju set-env` **worked**. and did set proxy in all machines.

This is how I tested. Instead of using curl on master machine.

- `juju run "curl https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Ajuju-gui" --all` and it failed in all nodes.
- `juju run "env | grep proxy" --all` in all machines and saw none have proxy related environment variables set.
- `juju set-env http-proxy=http://PROXY_IP:8080/` and `https-proxy`
- `juju run "env | grep proxy" --all` now returned proxy variables set in all machines